# Install Linux to SSD or HDD for virtualizing Windows with QEMU?

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, qemu, ssd

In my PC I have 1 TB slow HDD and 120 GB fast SSD. I am curious which one of my drives should be used for Ubuntu installation.

I plan to use Windows without dual-boot - by virtualizing it with QEMU (IOMMU, VT-d). E.g. I am going to use QEMU virtual HDD files as HDD in guest Windows.

I wonder if there is any difference if the virtual HDD file will be on "clean" SSD, or it will share same drive with Ubuntu installation. **Can I improve Windows guest performance by keeping host OS on another HDD than guests's HDD, or it is completely irrelevant for QEMU?**

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- Make sure, I have at a minimum 8GiB RAM.
- Install Linux into to a 12-15GiB Partition @SSD, add Swap@SSD, if wanted/needed.
- That should leave ~ 80GiB free on the SSD. Make a Partition, SSD3.
- Give that to the Virtual Machine for later use as Windows system drive.
- Create 2 Partitions on HDD, ~200GiB HDD1, and the Rest, HDD2
- Give HDD1 to the Windows Machine too, that will be "D:" with "\Users" on it.
- LVM HDD2, use on Linux, and Windows (by local-machine CIFS sharing)